PrimeFaces 13 tags not correctly rendered PrimeIcons
I updated primefaces 12 to primefaces 13.0.6-jakarta. Configuration in faces-config and web.xml are correct. I have my own renderers in faces-config. Now I see that in every page header frames, text fields and button possitions are totally shiffted. In browser console I see errors:
jakarta.faces.resource/primeicons/primeicons.woff2.faces.resource/primeicons/primeicons.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=13.0.6&e=13.0.6:1
   `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

jakarta.faces.resource/primeicons/primeicons.woff.faces.resource/primeicons/primeicons.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=13.0.6&e=13.0.6:1
   `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

jakarta.faces.resource/primeicons/primeicons.ttf.faces.resource/primeicons/primeicons.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=13.0.6&e=13.0.6:1
I never used primeicons. Strange that the url is combines two files, which are existing separatelly. I can access .ttf and .css. What can be wrong?
Here are rendereres in faces-config:
  <render-kit>
    <renderer>
      <component-family>jakarta.faces.Output</component-family>
      <renderer-type>jakarta.faces.resource.Stylesheet</renderer-type>
      <renderer-class>racoonML.presentation.faces.AekoStylesheetRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
    <renderer>
      <component-family>jakarta.faces.Output</component-family>
      <renderer-type>jakarta.faces.resource.Script</renderer-type>
      <renderer-class>racoonML.presentation.faces.AekoScriptRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
  </render-kit>

Dependencies:
<dependency org="jakarta.platform" name="jakarta.jakartaee-api" rev="10.0.0" />
        <dependency org="org.glassfish" name="jakarta.faces" rev="4.0.7" />

        <dependency org="org.primefaces" name="primefaces" rev="13.0.6" >
            <artifact name="primefaces" extra:classifier="jakarta" type="jar" />
            <artifact name="primefaces" extra:classifier="jakarta" type="source" ext="jar" />
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="org.primefaces.extensions" name="primefaces-extensions" rev="13.0.6" >
            <artifact name="primefaces-extensions" extra:classifier="jakarta" type="jar" />
        </dependency> 

I had to also have org.glassfish beceause I need com.sun.faces.Util package for diffrent purposes.
Thanks in advance for any help!
I tried to add manually in xhtml declaration to primeicons but from version 11 this is automatically added to every page.
I tried to change the implemetation of renderers but they are working correctly regarding other css and js files.

I am having no issues.  Is it a bug in your custom renderkits's?  You didn't post he code of what those renderkits are doing?  Does your code work if you remove those?
